# Visual Studio: Given Path Not Supported Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, path

I'm working on a program that will read in a .lsp file, read it, partially understand and comment on it, and then write the edited version back to the same directory with a .txt attachment.  The problem I am encountering is that visual studio throws a "Given path not supported" error when I try to run the program, which is likely due to some oversight on my part.  Can anyone spot a part of my code that would cause the filepath to become invalid?

```
Stream myStream = null;
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\All Code\clearspan-autocad-tools-development\Code\Lisp";
openFileDialog1.Filter = "LISP files (*.lsp)|*.lsp|All files (*.*)|*.*";
openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
string loc;

if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    try
    {
        if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
        {
            using (myStream)
            {
                string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                // saves the document with the same name of the LISP file, but with a .txt file extension
                using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory + "\\" + openFileDialog1.FileName.Substring(0, openFileDialog1.FileName.Length - 4) + ".txt"))
                {
                    foreach (string line in lines)
                    {
                        sr.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

EDIT: The filepath variable comes out to be "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\All Code\clearspan-autocad-tools-development\Code\Lisp\heel.lsp"

Also, the error occurs on the line where I attempt to initialize the StreamWriter and adjust the file path to be a .txt file.

Comment: Which line throws the error?  And what are the runtime values of the variables on that line?

Comment: Aside:  you could avoid all of that nasty string manipulation by using the methods provided by `System.IO.Path`.  Namely `Path.Combine()` and `Path.ChangeExtension()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`openFileDialog.FileName`  returns the full path to a file not just its name as the function implies.

So attempting to combine it with  `openFileDialog.InitialDirectory` makes a string unlike what you are expecting

You can use the change extension method to change it the filetype of your output

> var txtFile= Path.ChangeExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName, ".txt");

Answer (score 4):

`openFileDialog.FileName` already includes the path, so combining it with `openFileDialog.InitialDirectory` makes it a path like `C:\...\C:\...` which is invalid.

So, just use

```
var txtFile= Path.ChangeExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName, ".txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several problems.

**Error handling:**
You apparently don't know what line the error is occurring on due to your error handling.  It might be useful to go without that for debugging.

**Looping:**
You're pulling the whole input file into memory, then looping through each line to write it.  If the files to be processed are small enough, that will work, but I'd move the `foreach` loop outside of the block that reads the file.

**String Parsing:**
I recommend storing the path and filename in variables rather than just referencing the control.  This will make it more readable.  Also, `System.IO.Path.Combine()` can help build paths without having to worry about string concatenation.

**Overall:**
You may want to refactor this into a method, with a signature like this:

```
void ProcessLispFile(string inputFile, string outputFile) { }
```

Comment: That's all true, but not the answer.

Comment: Thomas, it may not have been the answer, but following my advice would have pointed out the issue.